# CodeAcademy: JavaScript Second "For" Loop in Text search

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, search

So, it's about making a text search. I was told to start with 3 var: text, myNames, and hits. I was supposed to push my name that I had placed within the 'text' to 'hits'.

I understand the first for loop, which is to search through the text with:

```js
for ( i = 0 ; i <= text.length ; i++ ) {
    if(text[i] === "S"); 
}
```

But then, I don't really understand the instruction,"So if your name is 11 letters long, your loop should add 11 characters to hits if it ever sees the first letter of myName in text."

So I checked the hint, which got me more confused, it says: "Your loop should stop when it hits the value of the first iterator (say, i) plus the length of your myName variable."

What? I tried to follow the hint, and it seemed true because it allowed me to go to the next lesson. But the console merely logged 'S'

```js
var text ="A string containing some text. \ I place my name here, Smit, \ a couple of times, so \ I need at least one more, \ Smit is it enough? \ Or we need more? \ Smit Smit Smit!"; 

var myName = "Smit";

var hits = [];

for ( i = 0 ; i <= text.length ; i++ ) {
    if(text[i] === "S"); {
        for ( j = i ; j <= (text.length + myName.length); j++ ) {
        hits.push("S");}
            
        }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YhFn.jpg)

But I don't understand why did I need to use "(text.length + myName.length)"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the instruction.

The instruction "So if your name is 11 letters long, your loop should add 11 characters to hits if it ever sees the first letter of myName in text" means the following code.

```
for (j = i; j < (i + myName.length); j++)
```

You should use `i + myName.length` instead of `text.length + myName.length`. If the first character of `myName` lies on the `i`-th position, then the final character of `myName` will lie on the `(i + myName.length - 1)`-th position. You can write a few strings and check it yourself.

It seems that codecademy's checking is not very strict, so it doesn't mean that your code is 100% correct even if it allows you to move to the next section.

But I don't quite understand why the instruction says "add 11 characters to hits if it ever sees the first letter of myName in text". Shouldn't we check the whole name and then decide to push it into `hit` or not?

Comment: Yeah, it only logged "S"